# Installing library into yocto rootfs

Tags: yocto

I am working on yocto i have compiled a library using yocto, which installed library inside

`/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/lib-ad/git-r0/package/usr/lib/libad.a`

Now inside my recipe i have included

```
FILES_${PN} += " \
    libad.a \
"
```

Now this is adding this file into `build-corei7-64/tmp/sysroots/corei7-64/usr/lib/libad.a`

but not into final rootfs, I assume `FILES_${PN}` will copy my files into rootfs. 
but this is not happening.
Any help is appreciated, Thank You

Comment: can you please provide your whole recipe and info on contents of your recipe folder(for example, "tree" command inside your recipe folder)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, up to now you managed to build and package your code correctly.
I guess you mean with rootfs the image that you build. To add a package to an image you can set `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "lib-ad"` within your local conf